# Create a python file that asks user 4 digit pin

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, user-input, counter

I have an assignment where I have to ask the user for a 4 digit pin. The correct pin is 1234. I have to give the user 3 times before they're locked out. I also have to add a break statement. This is the example of the output:

Please enter your pin code: 1112

Incorrect. Please enter again: 1112

Incorrect. Please enter again: 1234

Correct.

My code:

```
def verify_pin(pin)
if pin == "1234"
   return True
else:
   return False

tries = 3
while counter < 3:
  pin = input("please enter your pin code")
  if verify_pin(pin)     
  print("Correct")
  break
elif 
   print("Incorrect.Please enter again: ")
tries +=1
```

I received an invalid syntax. I don't know what I am doing at all but I really want to understand and learn. Please help.

Comment: Indentation is a problem here, also you need a colon , after `if` statements, instead of `if verify_pin(pin)`, you need `if verify_pin(pin):`.

Answer (score 1):

You are sort of close, but you have some issues with the code (mainly indentation issues, as mentioned in comments). Something like this should work though:

```py
desired_pin = '1234'
max_tries = 3


def verify_pin(the_pin):
    return the_pin == desired_pin


def main():
    tries = 0

    while tries < max_tries:
        pin = input('please enter your pin code: ')
        if verify_pin(pin):
            print('Correct')
            break
        else:
            print('Incorrect. Please enter again: ')
        tries += 1

    else:   # Else will run when no `break` statement is run in while loop.
        print("I am LOCKIN' you out now!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sample interaction:

```
please enter your pin code: 111
Incorrect. Please enter again: 
please enter your pin code: 222
Incorrect. Please enter again: 
please enter your pin code: 123
Incorrect. Please enter again: 
I am LOCKIN' you out now!
```

Comment: for def verify_pin(the pin) there is an invalid syntax

Comment: @DD01 it should be valid code actually. there is an underscore between, so like `the_pin`. But agreed, with the space in between it would be an invalid variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You have made some indentation and syntax errors. I have made some changes, please compare this with your code and you can understand the difference

```
def verify_pin(pin):
    if pin == "1234":
       return True
    else:
       return False

tries = 0
while tries < 3:
    pin = input("please enter your pin code")
    if verify_pin(pin):    
        print("Correct")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect.Please enter again: ")
    tries +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having syntax & indent issues kindly check the below code

```
def verify_pin(pin):
    if pin == "1234":
        return True
    else:
        return False


tries = 0
while tries < 3:
    pin = input("please enter your pin code")
    if verify_pin(pin):
        print("Correct")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect.Please enter again: ")
        at = 2 - tries
        print("You Have %s More Attempt Remaining" % at)
    tries += 1
```